# Read Serilog logs from MS-SQL (EntityFramework?)

Tags: entity-framework, serilog

What would you suggest for reading logs created by Serilog on a MS-SQL database?
I am already using EF for the persistence layer in the project.

Should I add new models in the domain layer to represent the logs I want to read, and just use EF to read them?
Or should I not add them to the EF db context and write individual DB queries? (Alternatively, I could write stored procedures and call those from code)

Comment: I'd suggest not reinventing the wheel and using [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) instead

Comment: This is an enterprise piece of software for which my company is not going to pay any license, so that it out of question unfortunately..